# Imprimir PDF directamente

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

Estoy trabajando con JSF y Jaspereports y lo que necesito es que cuando yo le de click a un boton para imprimir un PDF me salga inmediatamente el cuadro para imprimir éste PDF, ya he buscado varias herramientas como el printer d eprimefaces, printerjob etc... pero ninguna me ha servido hasta el momento, ya que no necesito que el archivo se guarde en el equipo, ya que tengo los byte en la memoria y necesito usar solo esa información.

Alguno sabe de alguna herramienta que me pueda ayudar con esto en JSF?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Yo he tratado de hacer eso también pero la única solución que encontré no fue utilizando Jasperreportes. Lo que hice fue crear la estructura del reporte en HTML, rellenar los datos, lanzarlo en un `window.open` y al `window.open` hacerle un `window.print` para que de una vez apareciera el cuadro de diálogo de impresión.

Comment: Sí, he visto ejemplos para hacerlo de esa forma y creo que lo haré así. Muchas gracias :D